# CATextLayer/NSAttributedString - Determine exact size of the shown text

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, core-text, catextlayer

I've got a CATextLayer with an NSAttributedString and I want to calculate the exact size of the visible/drawn text.

I have tried this:
http://www.taffysoft.com/pages/20120202-01.html

But it gives the same result for the string "1" and "5", even if with my test font (AvenirNextCondensed) those two are cleary not the same width.

How can I calculate the exact size of the visible text?

Comment: Are you trying to respect kerning with text, on a path, something like this: http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Text-Path.html